# Source(s) for Chazon Ish and Rav Shach's position on Ir Hanidachat

Tags: rambam, maseches-sanhedrin, chazon-ish, rav-shach

We have been learning a Gemara on Masechet Sanhedrin that brings a Braita talking about Ir Hanidachat.

It's on טו: and as follows: 
 דתניא עד
 כמה עושין עיר הנדחת מי׳ ועד ק׳ דברי
 רבי יאשיה רבי יונתן אומר ימק׳ ועה רובו
 של שבט

On this Braita, we saw the Rambam holds that it is talking about number of sinners in the city. However, we found in the Metivta that Chazon Ish and also Rav Shach hold it's the number of inhabitants in the city to qualify as a potential Ir Hanidachat.

For Rav Shach, it says it's in his book Avi Ezri. However, we don't have the book and have searched online with no luck.

Would anyone have the book and check for us what it says on Perek 5 (Hilchot Sanhedrin) Halacha 1?

**We want to know what Rishon are Chazon Ish and Rav Shach relying on to contradict the Rambam's position.**

Comment: Do you know there is such a Rishon?

Comment: We don't know, but we assume an Acharon would rely on a Rishon to contradict Rambam! Right?

Comment: There is no Avi Ezri on this halakha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Avi Ezri on Hilkhot Avodah Zarah 4:2, R. Schach asks why the Rambam interprets the gemara as referring to the number of sinners, when this requirement is about the size of the city--to become an עיר הנדחת, the city cannot be a כפר or a כרך. What does this have to do with the number of people who sinned? He quotes the Minchat Chinukh (no. 464) and Chazon Ish (Sanhedrin 24:11) as asking the same question.

He then explains that according to the Rambam, the sinners on their own must constitute a "city" on their own--because even though עיר הנדחת is determined by the majority of the city, we do not look at the non-sinners as if they have sinned, so the sinners on their own must fulfill the population requirements of the city.

[I just came across an interesting Rogachover on this topic, צפנת פענח, תניינא, הל' עבודה זרה פ"ד ה"ב:

שם. ויהיו המודחים ממאה ועד כו'. הנה רבינו שינה מלשון הגמרא דבגמרא בסנהדרין דט"ו ע"ב מבואר דפליגי כמה יהא בעיר לא כמה יהיו הנדחים וא"כ אם העיר היתה מאה או היתה רובו של שבט אף שלא נדחה כל כך אז הוי זה הדין, ורבינו נקט שיהיו הנדחים כך. והנה לפשטות הגמ' דמאה ר"ל כל העיר, וקיי"ל בעירובין דף נ"ט גבי עיר דצריך נ' דיורים, ע"ש בדף ס' דשם גם נשי' וטף מצטרפי' וכאן גבי עיר הנדחת אי מצטרפין נשי' וטף ע' בירו' ובספרי ובתוספ', וא"כ אי הוי פחות מנ', וא"כ אי הוי פחות מנ' לא הוו נקרא יושבי עירם ולכך צריך ק'. ואם יהי' מחצה על מחצה בעיר הנדחת אין בש"ס הכרעה, ועי' סנהדר' דקי"א ע"ב במשנה עד שיודח רובו כו' או שהודח מיעוטו כו' אבל מחצה ע"מ אין הכרעה איך הוא הדין והוי בגדר ספק, עי' פסחים ד"ז וחולין דכ"ח וכ"מ בזה. ובירוש' סנהד' מבו' דסדום הוה בגדר עיר הנדחת וראי' מלוט שנאבדו הנכסים שלו וזהו מה ששאל אאע"ה אם יש בעיר חמישים צדיקים דאז יהיה בגדר מחע"מ, ואמר השופט כל הארץ לא יעשה משפט, ולא א' כמשפט, כי שאל מדוע אין בכל התורה פסק דין ברור למע"מ, ועיי' בירושלמי פ"י הל' ז' ובדברי הראב"ד בהשגות בהלכות מגילה עי"ש.